# Can you create a field that points to a specific File?

Tags: fields, files

Is there a way to create a Lookup Relationship field such that the field points to a Related File?

For example, in FSL we have the Asset object. Our users upload photos to an Asset object as Files. These photos are visible in the usual locations.

We want a field on Asset along the lines of "Primary Photo". The User should be able to select the appropriate File like they can for any other Lookup field.

However, when you create a new field of type "Lookup Relationship", there is no obvious way to select File/ContentDocument/ContentVersion/etc.